# How to get location information of image from unsplash API?

Tags: android, geotagging

I am trying to integrate Unsplash API in my android app. Could anyone please let me know if the API supports location where the image has taken (geotagging)? It is available only for a few images as far as I understand. Is it possible to get it for those images which have geotagging?

Regards,
Smitha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It gives you both image location (where the image was taken) and the user location (where the photographer is)

See [get-a-photo](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-photo) API doc. As you see in the doc, sometimes `location` might be nullable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saeed Masoumi I have one more question. I am using search with a keyword to get a bunch of photos. Is it possible to get the location of each photo with just search query or should I take the photo id of each photo and then get its location.

Comment: @SmithaMohan It's not possible you must take the photo id of each photo and then get its location in a separate call